# How do I display the frequency of a phrase within text from a dictionary to a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to complete my homework assignment for my introductory programming class. I believe that I am approaching a viable solution with my code, but, I am struggling to understand how to switch between adding data to a dictionary, and then displaying that data as a list of tuples. How do I display the frequency of phrases in the form of a list of tuples when I have placed data into a dictionary?

Here is my homework prompt, associated test cases, and the current code I have written:

Write a function called phrase_freq that takes as input two file name strings.  The 
first file name refers to a file containing a book. The second file name contains 
phrases, one phrase to a line. The function uses a dictionary to map each 
phrase in the second file to an integer representing the number of times the phrase 
appears in the first file.  Phrases should be counted regardless of their capitalization
(e.g., if the phrase is "The Goops", then the phrases "The goops", "the Goops", and 
"the goops", should be counted).  The function returns a list of tuples containing the phrase and the number of times the phrase appears, sorted from largest number of appearances 
to the smallest.

```
#test cases
"""
>>> phrase_freq("goops.txt","small_phrase.txt")
[('The Goops', 11)]
>>> phrase_freq("goops.txt","large_phrase.txt")
[('The Goops', 11), ('a Goop', 9), ('your mother', 5), ('you know', 3), ('your father', 3), ('never knew', 2), ('forget it', 1)]
"""


def phrase_freq(file1, file2):   

    text_list =[]
    text_dict = {}

    in_file = open(file1)
    for data in in_file:
        a_dict += data
    in_file.close()

    in_file_2 = open(file2)
    key = data
    val = 0
    for other_data in in_file_2: 
        if key in file2: 
            a_dict[key] = a_dict[key] + 1
            else: 
                a_dict[key] = 1           
    in_file_2.close()   

    return a_dict
```

Thank you so much!

EDIT:

I have corrected code to this. I had some variable name inconsistencies, some indentation errors, and edited my return statement to format the output properly.

(Ignore the comments for myself)

```
def phrase_freq(file1, file2):   
#1. Initialize a dictionary. 
    a_dict = {}
#2. Open the file containing the phrases from the book.
    in_file = open(file1)
#3. Iterate though the data in the phrases file. 
    for data in in_file:
#4. Add this data into the dictionary.
        a_dict += data
#5. Close this file. 
    in_file.close()
#6. Open the file containing text from book.
    in_file_2 = open(file2)
    key = data
    val = 0
    for other_data in in_file_2: 
        if key in file2: 
            a_dict[key] = a_dict[key] + 1
        else: 
             a_dict[key] = 1           
    in_file_2.close()   

    return list(a_dict.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.items()` method of the `dict` class to get the key-value pairs from a dictionary. This returns a view object, so you need to build a `list` from it with the `list()` constructor:

```
freq_dict = {'the goops': 11, 'you know': 3}

freq_as_tuples = list(freq_dict.items())

print(freq_as_tuples)
```

Output:

```
[('the goops', 11), ('you know', 3)]
```

Assumming your counting logic is correct, this is how you can get tuples from a dict

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new at programming. Where would that fit into my current code?

Comment: The return statement `return list(a_dict.items())`

Comment: Is the code preceding that appropriate for the problem? If not, what changes do you recommend?

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it work? Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have run the code and it gives me the following error:     else: 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm not really sure why that would be considered a Syntax error.

Comment: The `else` needs to be in the same indent level as the corresponding `if`

Comment: The next error I am getting is:  a_dict += data
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'. Could I just make the dictionary equal to the data?